# Blocked Wordpress /wp-admin but still under attack

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Thinking I was being a good developer I blocked access to Wordpress admin using this .htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^XX.XX.XX.XX$     #My IP Address
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

I have Sucuri on the website and it is informing me that someone is trying to hack in by using versions of Author usernames, problem is their IP address changes constantly so I cannot add a Deny.

I cannot get to the admin with this above htaccess code (if I remove my IP address!) ... how are they!?

Thanks, J

Comment: I have wordfence installed, and it blocks these kind of attacks. Also check if they're not targeting `xmlrpc.php`, if they are, and you're not using it (jetpack, rest use it), you can disable it with a plugin.

Comment: Interesting @dingo_d do you go for Premium or is Free good enough. I am going to be looking for something like this but for the whole webserver I think.

Answer (score 0):

try adding/editing .htaccess in wp-admin folder directly:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx #your IP
```

Comment: Thanks @niklaz I have just added that and tested. It works to block me out, but the hacker/bot is still somehow getting through.

Comment: @JayUK, please, check for files bot tries to access within wp-admin, if you have access to access.log